# ¿Cómo insertar datos en Firebase de manera individual sin usar colecciones?

Tags: json, base-de-datos, firebase, ionic4

Estoy intentado meter en Firebase estos datos, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Quiero hacer lo de este video pero en vez de local, tener los datos en Cloud Firebase.

Video: https://youtu.be/6sXz2swm6Sw?t=115

```
  private data = [
     {
       category: 'Pizza',
       expanded: true,
       products: [
         { id: 0, name: 'Peperoni', price: '29.99', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 1, name: 'X', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 2, name: 'XX', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 3, name: 'XXX', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
       ]
     },
     {
       category: 'Bebida',
       products: [
         { id: 4, name: 'S', price: '29.99', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 5, name: 'ss', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 6, name: 'sXX', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 7, name: 'XSSXX', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
       ]
     },
     {
       category: 'Extras',
       products: [
         { id: 8, name: 'Saayer', price: '29.99', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 9, name: 'Xjhj', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
         { id: 10, name: 'XhjhgX', price: '15.85', cantidad: 1},
       ]
     }
   ];
```

Comment: que código usas para meterlo ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén perdona, soy nuevo aquí y no se usar bien esto. Lo que estoy haciendo es meter los datos manualmente, pero no se como hacerlo en Firebase, osea, tal cual lo tengo ahí. Puedo meter por separado cada cosa, pero no sabría que categoría es... es algo complicado, tampoco se explicarme ben.